# When I try to display contents on Applications folder in Terminal, I got "Chrome Apps.localized"

Tags: java, macos, spring-security, terminal, shibboleth

Hkellys-MacBook-Pro:~ hkelly$ cd Applications

Hkellys-MacBook-Pro:Applications hkellys$ ls

Chrome Apps.localized

Your feedback is appereciated.

Comment: Where is Java involved here?

Comment: Sorry - I'm first timer poster here. Basically the goal is to set up a working Shibboleth on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling the system to list the contents of the `Applications` folder inside your home directory `/Users/hkelly`. There's an item called `Chrome Apps.localized` in there which is a folder that the Google Chrome browser creates when installed. To list the contents of the Applications folder containing your installed applications, use

```
cd /Applications
ls
```

If you're trying to install Shibboleth, follow [this tutorial](http://www.jeesty.com/shibboleth).
You might also want to read a [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line) on how to use Terminal.

Comment: Thank you. cd /Applications worked for me. thank you for the tutorials as well.